# Chart.js - loading multiple charts with draggable datapoints into a single HTML Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

We're trying to load multiple line charts into one single page.
There is a simplified instance here - JSFiddle.

- Canvases and instances have different names
- We have used a JQuery wrapper to isolate the instantiation code.

Issue is that an offset is generated on dragging a data point so that the drag offset changes with each added instance. Just two instances are shown in the fiddle

We notice that the dynamic iframe generated by Chart.JS looks weird (developer tools)
Any comments / tips appreciated

Comment: "Just two instances are shown in the fiddle" What fiddle?

Comment: Ooops - yes could help! https://jsfiddle.net/prema770/tnkdmyh7/105/

Comment: The link you posted gives a 404.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that a different approach worked faultlessly.  It appears that the original code sample we based our approach on was flawed. Thanks very much for looking at this